# Cassandra-SelectQuery-retrieve first record of each minute-based on second

Tags: cassandra, cql

Can someone tell me how to write select query to return first record of each minute ?
First record here refers to first record of each minute (based on seconds). Please see example below.
My System is going to regulary receive data for every 5 seconds from device.
My Table structure is going to be like this.

```
CREATE TABLE device (
    deviceId text,
    datetime timestamp,
    temp float,
    volt float,
    PRIMARY KEY (deviceId, datetime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (datetime DESC);
```

Is it possible to extract the datetime in select query , process it and find the first record of each minute?

```
insert into device (deviceId,datetime,temp,volt)
values ('device123','2018-10-10 5:10:00+0000',0.12,6.7);
insert into device (deviceId,datetime,temp,volt)
values ('device123','2018-10-10 5:10:05+0000',3.12,61.7);
insert into device (deviceId,datetime,temp,volt)
values ('device123','2018-10-10 5:10:10+0000',2.12,16.7);
insert into device (deviceId,datetime,temp,volt)
values ('device123','2018-10-10 5:10:15+0000',1.12,26.7);

insert into device (deviceId,datetime,temp,volt)
values ('device123','2018-10-10 5:11:20+0000',4.12,11.7);
insert into device (deviceId,datetime,temp,volt)
values ('device123','2018-10-10 5:11:25+0000',5.12,12.7);
insert into device (deviceId,datetime,temp,volt)
values ('device123','2018-10-10 5:11:30+0000',6.12,23.7);
insert into device (deviceId,datetime,temp,volt)
values ('device123','2018-10-10 5:11:35+0000',7.12,126.7);
```

My Query should give me the result like this:

- For 10th minute, second=00  temp=0.12, volt = 6.7
- For 11th minute,second=20 temp=4.12, volt = 11.7

Can you provide suggestions as to how I can achive this in cassandra?

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra, you typically have to build your tables to fit your query pattern.  So you could build a table which only held the first entry for each minute's worth    of data, using the model above.

Or, you could build a table to `partition` the data out by minute.  In this case, you would need to add one more partition key to your table, `minute_bucket`.  Also, to pull back the "first" (or earliest) row per minute, flip the sort direction on the `datetime` clustering key to ascending (`ASC`).  Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE device_by_minute (
    deviceId text,
    datetime timestamp,
    minute_bucket text,
    temp float,
    volt float,
    PRIMARY KEY ((deviceId, minute_bucket), datetime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (datetime ASC);
```

Then (after loading data), run a multi-key query using the `PER PARTITION LIMIT` clause, like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM device_by_minute
    WHERE deviceid='device123'
      AND minute_bucket IN ('2018-10-10 05:10','2018-10-10 05:11')
    PER PARTITION LIMIT 1;

 deviceid  | minute_bucket    | datetime                        | temp | volt
-----------+------------------+---------------------------------+------+------
 device123 | 2018-10-10 05:10 | 2018-10-10 05:10:00.000000+0000 | 0.12 |  6.7
 device123 | 2018-10-10 05:11 | 2018-10-10 05:11:20.000000+0000 | 4.12 | 11.7

(2 rows)
```

Notes:

- Multi-key queries like this using an `IN` clause on *part* of the partition key will prevent Cassandra from figuring out which node contains the data at query time.  It will then designate a "coordinator node" to handle result set compilation, as well as communication with nodes containing the requested replicas.  Relative to a query on the full partition key, **this will not perform as well**.
- This query could be simplified by running a `SELECT * FROM device_by_minute PER PARTITION LIMIT 1;`.  However, query performance will get worse as the data set grows.  It's still better to limit the potential result set in the `WHERE` clause.
- I would keep the number items in the `IN` clause at low single-digits.